# Tkinter Создание изображений в виджете Text

Tags: python, tkinter, pillow

Я пытаюсь вставить картинку в текстовый виджет с помощью `PhotoImage` из https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html

```python
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(win)
text.pack()
file = 'images/python.jpg'
image = tk.PhotoImage(file=file)
text.image_create('end', image=image)

win.mainloop()
```

Выбрасывает ошибку:

```
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "images/python.jpg"
```

Решил попробовать через `PIL`:

```python
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

win = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(win)
text.pack()
file = 'images/python.jpg'

img = Image.open(file)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
text.image_create('end', image=image)

win.mainloop()
```

вроде всё отлично работает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но когда я пытаюсь засунуть добавление картинки в процедуру:

```python
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

win = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(win)
text.pack()
file = 'images/python.jpg'
def add_image():
    img = Image.open(file)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    text.image_create('end', image=image)
add_image()
win.mainloop()
```

То изображение становится пустым:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал через

```python
with Image.open(file) as img:
```

(чтобы файл закрывался)
Но ничего не менялось.
Не понимаю в чём проблема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Tkinter поддерживает только форматы .gif, .ppm, .pnm и .png, поэтому в первой попытке ошибка.(.jpg)

> Out of the box, Tk 8.5 includes support for GIF and PPM/PNM images. Tk 8.6 added PNG to this short list.
> https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/fonts.html

2. Чтоб вашу картинку при выходе из функции не съел сборщик мусора, надо определить её в функции как глобальную -  global image.

Comment: Спасибо большое.